# How to echo an error div if the reCaptcha isn't confirm

Tags: php, html, email, recaptcha

I have a script and it runs very well, but I want know how to echo an error div if recaptcha isn't confirmed. In this script if recaptcha wasn't confirmed the page will reload and nothing will be send to my mail, but I don't know how to display an error that tells the user: "You must verificate that you aren't a robot".
Can you help me?
CODE:

```
<?php
echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../support/style/contactform.css\">\n";
$emailpattern="^[^@ ]+@[^@ ]+\.[^@ \.]+$";
 if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
  $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}
if(!$captcha){
  echo '<form method="post" id="contactformall">
<p>Nome</p>
<input type="text" name="name" class="contactformimput"/>
<p>Email (obbligatorio)</p>
<input type="text" name="email" class="contactformimput"/>
<p>Numero</p>
<input type="text" name="number" class="contactformimput"/>
<p>Messaggio (obbligatorio)</p>
<input type="text" name="message" onkeyup="adjust_textarea(this)" class="contactformimput" id="contactformtext">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="____key____"></div>
<div id="divcontactbutton">
<input type="reset" name="send" value="Resetta" class="button" id="resetmessage"/>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Invia Messaggio" class="button" id="sendmessage"/>
</div>
</form>';
    exit;
}
   $responsejson=file_get_contents("google.com/recaptcha/api/…); 
$response = json_decode($responsejson); 
if($response->success==false) { echo "<div class=\"emailerror\" id=\"emailnoninviata\"><div><span>•</span> Email non inviata</div></div>";  
**/////THIS part DON'T RUN**
}else
{
      if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
          if(!ereg($emailpattern,$_POST['email'])) {
              $emailerror = true;
               echo "<div class=\"emailerror\"><div><span>6</span> Email non valida</div></div>";
          } if ($_POST['message'] == "") {
              $emailerror = true;
              echo "<div class=\"emailerror\"><div><span>6</span> Inserisci un messaggio</div></div>";
          } elseif  ($_POST['message'] != "" and ereg($emailpattern,$_POST['email'])){
              $emailerror = false;
          };
          if ($emailerror == true) {
              echo '<form method="post">
  <p>Nome</p>
 <input type="text" name="name" class="contactformimput"/>
 <p>Email*</p>
 <input type="text" name="email" class="contactformimput"/>
 <p>Numero</p>
 <input type="text" name="number" class="contactformimput"/>
 <p>Messaggio*</p>
 <input type="text" name="message" onkeyup="adjust_textarea(this)" class="contactformimput" id="contactformtext">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="___KEY___"></div>
<div id="divcontactbutton">
<input type="reset" name="send" value="Resetta" class="button" id="resetmessage"/>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Invia Messaggio" class="button" id="sendmessage"/>
</div>
  </form>'; 
          }
          if (isset($_POST['send']) and $emailerror == false) {
            $to = "mail@gmail.com";
            $subject = "B&B";
            $user_name = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n";
            $user_email = 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
            $user_ip = 'IP: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n";
            $user_message = 'Message: ' . $_POST['message'];
            $message = $user_name . $user_email . $user_ip . $user_message;
            $success = mail($to, $subject, $message);
            echo "<div class=\"emailerror\" id=\"emailinviata\"><div>  <span>5</span> Email inviata correttamente</div></div>";}
}
}

  ?>
```

Comment: `$response.success` looks like a problem.

Comment: PHP uses no dots as far as I know. Are you sure $response.success is the right way to check if the typed characters match the captcha? I've never used reCAPTCHA so I honestly don't know either.

Comment: I chane with this but it doesn't run.

$responsejson=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=key&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 $response = json_decode($responsejson);
    if($response->success==false)
    {
        echo "<div class=\"emailerror\" id=\"emailnoninviata\"><div><span>•</span> Email non inviata</div></div>";
    }else .......

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing javascript code with php code. Javascripts uses '.' to access class vars/functions, php uses '->'.

Please read this page in order to use Recaptcha with php: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php

Comment: I chane with this but it doesn't run.

$responsejson=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=key&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 $response = json_decode($responsejson);
    if($response->success==false)
    {
        echo "<div class=\"emailerror\" id=\"emailnoninviata\"><div><span>•</span> Email non inviata</div></div>";
    }else .......

Answer (score 0):

The [recaptcha documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) shows that this API request should return JSON. You will need to decode the JSON response to refer to its contents. So do this after you use `file_get_contents()` to get the response:

```
$response = json_decode($response);
```

and then you should be able to check for success with a little adjustment to your syntax.

```
if($response->success==false)
```

Comment: I chane with this but it doesn't run.

$responsejson=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=key&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 $response = json_decode($responsejson);
    if($response->success==false)
    {
        echo "<div class=\"emailerror\" id=\"emailnoninviata\"><div><span>•</span> Email non inviata</div></div>";
    }else .......